# Official presence at HeroesCon - Charlotte, NC - June 22-24

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Stack Exchange will be officially attending [HeroesCon in Charlotte, North Carolina](http://www.heroesonline.com/heroescon/) (June 22-24). We will be there spreading the word about SciFi.SE and, hopefully, meeting all of our local users. We're also hosting a pre-party in the area that Thursday night. Here's a rundown of what we're doing at HeroesCon:

- **Thursday, June 21st** - [HeroesCon pre-party at Spandex City comic shop](http://spandexcity.com/home.php). This will be running in conjunction with that night's HeroClix tournament and will feature the cast and crew behind [The Question in Conference Room B](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wt8lKPb60Xo&feature=plcp) hanging out, giving out SciFi.SE swag. More details about the pre-party are being worked out, but I know there will be door prizes and 3-day passes to the con given out.
- **Friday, June 22nd - Sunday, June 24th** - We will be in the Small Press area with a table. Between the show program, our Stack Exchange banner and spinning wheel, we should be easy to find. Please come by and say hello! We will be doing live demonstrations of the site, challenging people with our spinning trivia wheel, and giving out SciFi.SE swag. Perhaps you can win one of these new, [just-got-in-the-office tote bags](http://stackexchange.tumblr.com/post/24970061155/the-all-new-fresh-in-the-box-sci-fi-fantasy)?!
- We will be creating [video content](http://www.youtube.com/user/StackHQ), asking the creators questions about the material they created and shooting a special episode of The Question in Conference Room B from the show floor.
- We will also be blogging from the show floor, probably frequently from our [Tumblr](http://stackexchange.tumblr.com/), and end-of-day recaps at our [official blog](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/).

If you are attending HeroesCon, please let us know! Please come by Spandex City on Thursday or our booth over the weekend. Introduce yourself! If you are interested in being part of some unofficial street team, let us know! Email me at **brett at stack exchange dot com**. We'll get you a street team kit set aside and you can pick it up at the con.

Hope to see some of y'all there!

Comment: I with I could attend! An ex of mine lives there tho so I don't know I I'd want to go lol...

Comment: Oh heck yes! Now I have to somehow single-handedly drive up Charlotte web traffic after the con so StackExchange will keep doing them...

Comment: @IanPugsley  I'll occasionally help you